# Who was the first to posit that "culture determines the moral status of things within that culture"?

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-culture

I am studying moral philosophy and I wish to learn who was the first to posit the above quote, preferably in similar wording as above.

Comment: according to google, it was quizlet. the first cultural relativist?

Comment: actually, i think you. :D

Comment: If you wish to study moral philosophy you should look deeper than the origin of formulaic quotes on midterm flashcards posted online. On historical background of moral relativism see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-relativism/#HisBac). Protagoras's quote "*"Man is the measure of all things, of the things that are, that they are, and of the things that are not, that they are not*" is often seen as one of the earliest expressions.

Comment: @Conifold Actually I am trying to determine if someone plagiarized that phrase(among others) in his Phd thesis

Comment: @Conifold for instance that person uses the phrase “culture determines the moral status of all entities ” and also uses this phrase "On
this definition, all moral agents are also moral patients, but not all moral patients are
moral agents" that is too found in a flashcard here https://quizlet.com/348405454/ethics-exam-3-flash-cards/ as "all moral agents are also moral patients, but not all moral patients are moral agents" . Is this plagiarism if he does it without citations?

Comment: If they copied it from flashcards to their dissertation without attribution (and they should really use a more credible source than online flashcards) then yes, it is plagiarism. But such issues should be asked about on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To be sure, some of the intuitions underlying cultural relativism were
> around in various forms well before Herder. The most famous doctrine
> of the Ancient Greek Sophist Protagoras — the great foil in Socrates’
> and Plato’s search for universal truths — is that “man is the measure
> of all things,” but the focus of Protagoras’ relativism was not
> culture, but rather, the possibility of truth as such. Herodotus’
> presentation of events and various peoples in his History is
> thoroughly (often frustratingly and indiscriminately) non-judgmental,
> but he articulated no overarching belief or philosophical doctrine to
> ground his approach. It was perhaps Montaigne, in his essay “On
> Cannibals,” who came the closest to a direct statement of the cultural
> relativist position when he wrote that “everyone gives the title of
> barbarism to everything that is not in use in his own country. As,
> indeed, we have no other level of truth and reason than the example
> and idea of the opinions and customs of the place wherein we live:
> there is always the perfect religion, there the perfect government,
> there the most exact and accomplished usage of all things.” But
> Montaigne, though a brilliant writer and essayist, was not a
> philosopher

https://www.newenglishreview.org/Alexander_Zubatov/The_First_Cultural_Relativist:_Relativism,_Nationalism_and_the_Danger_of_Diversity/

This article suggests Johann Gottfried von Herder, though

> Johann Gottfried von Herder is not exactly a household name, and many
> of the few who know him may think of him chiefly as the eighteenth
> century philosopher who originated the nationalist conception of “the
> Volk” that the Nazis ran with and turned into their notion of Aryan
> racial purity. Herder’s view of the Jews doesn’t help his cause.

Good luck

Comment: While Herder certainly is a good contender, the quote you gave does not show why he may qualify and does not point out how your source is of relevance to the question. Maybe you could pick a relevant passage?